# EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION cause JVM crash

Tags: java, jvm

I am currently working on a java project(design a card game) and there is a method to choose the suitable card in a player's hand. But A fatal error happend irregularly (not in a fixed time). Here is the header of the log
*

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fffd58ba714, pid=5604, tid=0x0000000000004314
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_212-b10) (build 1.8.0_212-b10)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.212-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [zip.dll+0xa714]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

*
It seems like the problem happends in native C (# C  [zip.dll+0xa714]).How can I fix it? BTW, I have tried deploy a larger memory to JVM. It still happends sometime.

Comment: The JDK version I am using is jdk1.8.0_212. and sometimes the error is not shown,"Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)" instead shown in terminal. I don't know whether it is the same cause.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a more recent version. The latest Java 8 is Java 8 Update 252.

Comment: Can you show complete `hs_err_pid.log`?